# How to automatically check list length - function parameter in Python?

Tags: python, list, function

I have declared function:

```
def time_between_pulses_checking(self,
                                 channels: list,
                                 max_time_difference: float,
                                 active_pulse_level: int = 0) -> tuple:
```

When I want to call this function, I pass a list as the *channels* parameter. This list should contain at least 2 values.

I can check it with the following instruction:
`if len(channels) >= 2:`
but I would prefer that when calling the function there was a hint that, for example -> the list passed is too short.

How can I do this?

Comment: That _is_ how. You could move it to e.g. a decorator if you want to deduplicate its use in multiple functions.

Comment: What do you mean by a hint? Do you:
1. Expect the function to fail
2. Print a warning
3. Be colored with a warning in the IDE you're using

Comment: When I declare a parameter type in docstrings and when calling a function, I pass a different type as a parameter, I get a warning in pycharm. I would like to achieve something similar by passing a list of too short a length to a function.

Comment: @Jkozdoncher PyCharm can't know what the list will contain when the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't something supported by the newish Python type hints, but you could break down the channels into two separate arguments:

```
def time_between_pulses_checking(self,
                                 channel1,
                                 channel2,
                                 max_time_difference: float,
                                 active_pulse_level: int = 0) -> tuple:
```

If the number of channels is a variant then you could set as such:

```
def time_between_pulses_checking(self,
                                 *channels,
                                 max_time_difference: float,
                                 active_pulse_level: int = 0):
```

This way you can call it:

```
time_between_pulses_checking('ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3', 'chn',
                             max_time_difference=5)
```

The `max_time_difference` and `active_pulse_level` are keyword only arguments here.

You could use this to force at least two channels as:

```
def time_between_pulses_checking(self,
                                 channel_1,
                                 channel_2,
                                 /,
                                 *etc_channels,
                                 max_time_difference: float,
                                 active_pulse_level: int = 0):
```

Comment: This solution is ok when I expect only two channels. But 2 channels or more can be passed to the function.